# Print the substring that is present between two uppercase letters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
x = str(input())
w = ' '
w2 = ''
for i in x:
    if i.isupper() == True:
        w2 += w
    else:
        w2 += i
print(w2)
```

I have converted the uppercase alphabets to space, can anyone suggest me what to do next?

**Input:**  abCdefGh
**Expected output:**  def

Comment: i guess what you want is to get words between two uppercase word "C" and  "G". Right?

Comment: You never change the value of `w`.

Comment: yeah, I want words between two uppercase word "C" and "G"

Answer (score 1):

I use a flag to tag whether program should add character `i` into `w2`.
Notice the condition I write. It is the key of my code.

```py
x = "abCdefGh"
w2 = ''
inBetween = False

for i in x:
    if i.isupper():
        # Upper case denotes either start or end of substring
        if not inBetween:
            # start of substring
            inBetween = True
            continue
        else:
            # end of substring
            inBetween = False
            break
    if inBetween:
        w2+= i

print(w2)
```

Result is :

```
def
```

Comment: but this code is giving bef as the output and not def which is the correct one....

Answer (score 1):

To print the substring that is present between two uppercase letters in the string.

**Step 1:** Find the index position of the uppercase letter.

**Step 2:** Then slice the substring between the first element + 1 and the second element in the list (string[start: end])

```
word = "abCdefGh"

# Get indices of the capital letters in a string:
def getindices(word):
    indices = []
    for index, letter in enumerate(word):
        if (letter.isupper() == True):
            indices.append(index)
    return indices


if __name__ == "__main__":
    caps_indices = getindices(word)
    start = caps_indices[0] + 1
    end = caps_indices[1]
    print(word[start:end])
```

**Output:**

```
def
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` to extract text easily.

```
import re

# pattern to accept everything between the capital letters.
pattern = '[A-Z](.*?)[A-Z]'

# input string
input_string= 'thisiSmyString'
    
matched_string = re.findall(pattern, input_string)
print(matched_string[0])
```